# vue3: extends missing parent's setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**parent.vue**

```js
<template>
    <input :type="computedType"/>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    type: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: 'text',
    },
});

const showPassword = ref(false);
const computedType = computed(() => {
    if (props.type === 'password') {
        return showPassword.value ? 'text' : 'password';
    }
    return props.type;
});
</script>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
             uuid: getRandomUuid(),
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**child.vue**

```js
<template>
    <input :type="computedType"/>
</template>
<script>
import Parent from '~/components/parent.vue'
export default {
    extends: Parent
}
</script>
```

In Vue3, I have a `child.vue` component which is inherited from `parent.vue`, I defined a `computedType` computed attribute in `parent.vue`, but it's missing in `child.vue`, however, `uuid` which is defined in `parent.vue` is accessible in `child.vue`.

> [Vue warn]: Property "computedType" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

---

How to get `computedType` and any other attributes defined in `<script setup>` of `parent.vue` in `child.vue`?

Really appreciate any help provided!

---

update:

Only if I define all the attributes in `<script>`(but not in `setup()`) instead of `<script setup>`, they could be accessible

Comment: you should never have two script tags in the same component.  you should either write the component entirely with the options API (the only API that supports the "extends" option), or write entirely with the composition API where you would use [composable functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) to effectively extend your component

Comment: @yoduh but `inheritattrs` is only available in `<script>` instead of `<script setup>`, also one component with both `<script>` and `<script setup>` is working as expected, there is an example from [vue3 official document](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#inheritattrs) with two script tags

Comment: I doubt that setup function can be properly "inherited" with `extends`. Probably could be improved with custom merge strategy https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-optionmergestrategies

Comment: I stand corrected.  There _are_ a few specific instances where you can have more than one script tag, and they are all outlined [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) in the documentation.  Still, besides those 3 specific use cases, you shouldn't use more than one script tag.  Your case of a separate script tag for one data variable is not a valid use case

Comment: @yoduh Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right, post it as an answer

Comment: no problem! answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* a few specific instances where you can have more than one script tag, and they are all outlined [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) in the documentation. Still, besides those 3 specific use cases, you shouldn't use more than one script tag. Your case of a separate script tag for one data variable is not a valid use case.

I recommend writing the component entirely with the options API (the only API that supports the "extends" option), or writing entirely with the composition API where you would use [composable functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) to effectively extend your component

Answer (score 0):

defineExpose({computedType});
try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still does not work with same previous errors